# JQuery set z-index on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, z-index

I'm using this code to control a transform on elements. On click, I want to anything with the has-transform class to be set with a high z-index, say 99. Another click should set the z-index back to it's original value.

I tried adding this to the click function, but it had no effect:
$('.has-transform').css('z-index', 99);

/// the code   ///

```
<style>
  .has-transform, .transform_target .et-pb-icon {
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  } 
  .toggle-transform-animation {
    transform: none !important;
  }
  #transform_target {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .toggle-active-target.et_pb_blurb .et-pb-icon {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
</style>

<script>
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#transform_target').click(function(){
      $('.has-transform').toggleClass('toggle-transform-animation');
    });    
  });
})( jQuery );   
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML? You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Why don't you put the z-index in the CSS?

Answer (score -2):

If you have more than 1 element with the class `'.has-transform'`, the $('.has-transform') will return an iterable collection.

Each of the items in this collection needs to be handled separetly, each should have its own toggleClass method called:

```
$('.has-transform').each(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('toggle-transform-animation');
    // where this is an item of the collection
});
```

Comment: This is not necessary. `$('.has-transform').toggleClass('toggle-transform-animation')` should work just fine.

Comment: jQuery modification methods automatically iterate, that's one of its most useful features.